# High bandwidth Networking and the Windows "System Interrupts" Process

Tags: windows, networking, taskmanager, irq

I am writing a massive UDP network application.
Running traffic at 10gigabits per second.
I have a very high "System Interrupts" CPU usage in task manager.

Reading about what this means, I see:

> What Is the “System Interrupts” Process?
>
> System Interrupts is an official part of Windows and, while it does
>   appear as a process in Task Manager, it’s not really a process in the
>   traditional sense. Rather, it’s an aggregate placeholder used to
>   display the system resources used by all the hardware interrupts
>   happening on your PC.

However most articles say that a high value corresponds with failing hardware.

However, since the "system interrupts"  entry correlates to high IRQ usage, maybe this should be high considering my large UDP network usage.

Also, is all of this really happenning on one CPU core? Or is this an aggregate of all things happening across all CPU cores.

Comment: Why do you think it's happening on one CPU core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many individual datagrams being sent over UDP, it's certainly going to cause a lot of hardware interrupts, and a lot of CPU usage. 10 Gb is certainly in the range of "lots of CPU" if your datagrams are relatively small.

Each CPU has its own hardware interrupts. You can see how spread out the load is over cores on the performance tab - the red line is the kernel CPU time, which includes hardware interrupts and other low-level socket handling by the OS.